# How to show tooltip with jsx content inside it-Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I want to show a tooltip on hover, that tooltip has html jsx content. I used `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` to convert the jsx to string however the end result of the tooltip is :

```
<div>ABC</div>
 <div>ABC description</div>
  <div>ABC refreshed 1 min ago</div>
```

I want the tooltip to show the content within the html and not include the tags. How can I do that?

jsx:

```
render() {
  let tooltip = (
  <div>ABC</div>
 <div>ABC description</div>
  <div>ABC refreshed 1 min ago</div>
)
  return (
      <div><span data-tip={ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(tooltip)}>ABC info</span></div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a normal html element and use a css selector to show it when the other element is hovered. Here is an example:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.element:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="element">
  Hover me
  <span class="tooltip">I appear on hover!</span>
</span>
```

This is very simple and does not need any js logic in React.

Answer (score 0):

you have two problems really:

1. In your `tooltip` variable, you need to put some parent component to wrap the other `divs`, you could use => `<></>` or `<Fragment></Fragment>`.
2. You don't need all that logic in order to render a simple `tooltip`, [here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nxrvwl) a StackBlitz where you can see how to do it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using this

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Your Content</div>
```